# Data from android not posting on php

Tags: php, android, json, web-services, latitude-longitude

What I am trying is I get my current location (the coordinates) and i want to post those coordinates on a website. I have made a server using WAMP. I have written php code and the code in java. There is no error butno data is being posted on the website

PHP CODE

```
<?php
echo 'Hello, world!';
$json = $_GET['jsonpost'];//get the post you sent...
$data = json_decode($json); //decode the json formatted string...
print_r($data);
$id = $data->id;
$devid = $data->devid;
$latitude = $data->latitude;
$longitude = $data->longitude;
$service = $data->service;
$con = mysql_connect("","","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("a5234826_ul", $con);
$devid = $_POST['devid']; 
$latitude = $_POST['latitude'];
$longitude = $_POST['longitude'];
echo "devid" +$devid;
echo "latitude" + $latitude;
echo "longitude" + $longitude; 
$sql = "INSERT INTO  `a5234826_ul`.`locations` (
`id` ,
`devid` ,
`latitude` ,
`longitude` ,
`service`
)
VALUES (
NULL ,  '$devid',  '$latitude',  '$longitude', '$service'  
)";
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_close($con);
echo json_encode($variable);
?>
```

**EDITED**
LocationService.java

```
    @Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "lock");
    wl.acquire();
    context = this;
    final String who = intent.getStringExtra("who");
    final LocationManager locMan = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    final LocationListener listener = new LocationListener(){

        // start location changed

        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
            double latitude = loc.getLatitude();
            double longitude = loc.getLongitude();


            // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://.../serverFile.php");
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();


            TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            String devid = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();

            String postData = "{\"request\":{\"type\":\"locationinfo\"},\"userinfo\":{\"latitude\":\""+latitude+"\",\"longitude\":\""+longitude+"\",\"devid\":\""+devid+"\"}}";




            try {  

                json.put("longitude", longitude);//place each of the strings as you did in postData method
                json.put("latitude", latitude);

                json.put("devid", devid);

                JSONArray postjson=new JSONArray();
                postjson.put(json);
                httppost.setHeader("json",json.toString());
                httppost.getParams().setParameter("jsonpost",postjson);     
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                // for JSON retrieval:
                if(response != null)
                { 
                InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            try {
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                try {
                is.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
                }
                String jsonStr = sb.toString(); //take the string you built place in a string



                JSONObject rec = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                String longitudecord = rec.getString("lon");
                    String latitudecord = rec.getString("lat");
                // ...
                }
                }catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }




            if (who.equals("me")){
                Intent i = new Intent(context.getPackageName()+".LocationReceived");
                i.putExtra("lat", String.valueOf(latitude));
                i.putExtra("longitude", String.valueOf(longitude));
                i.putExtra("accuracy", String.valueOf(loc.getAccuracy()));
                context.sendBroadcast(i);
                Notification notif = new Notification();
                NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                notif.tickerText = "Location Found!";
                notif.icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
                notif.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                notif.when = System.currentTimeMillis();
                Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, TestLocatorActivity.class);
                notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                notificationIntent.putExtra("lat", String.valueOf(latitude));
                notificationIntent.putExtra("longitude", String.valueOf(longitude));
                notificationIntent.putExtra("accuracy", String.valueOf(loc.getAccuracy()));
                PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
                notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Location Found!", "Click to open.", contentIntent);
                nm.notify(0, notif);
            } else {
                SmsManager smsMan = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsMan.sendTextMessage(who, null, "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=loc:"+latitude+","+longitude, null, null);
                smsMan.sendTextMessage(who, null, "Latitude: "+latitude+"\nLongitude: "+longitude, null, null);
            }
            locMan.removeUpdates(this);
            try {
                wl.release();
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            stopSelf();
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){


        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            //Log.i(tag, "GPS IS ON");
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras){
            switch(status) {
                case LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE:
                case LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE:
                case LocationProvider.AVAILABLE:
                    break;
            }
        } };


    locMan.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listener);
    locMan.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listener);

    return 2;
}

}
```

Comment: Please start using mysqli, as mysql_ commands are not supported by the community.

Comment: are you using emulator? what is the value of your `postData` in java?

Comment: @Jack yeah!!! i am getting my location but its not posting.

Comment: @dynamic how do i use dat... i am new to android

Comment: mysqli is for your PHP code, not your Android code.

Comment: @dynamic Can you help me with the code...

Comment: [I'm actually going to bed right now, but this will.](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is their any connection to the server?

Did you check /etc/httpd/logs/.. or wherever your distribution logs http traffic?
I would do this first to determine that traffic is actually being sent from the device.

If successful, does the database get populated? You could also simply add statements to trace the php code to a file (in say /tmp) and tail that to see if the error resides in the code, or just to follow the code execution pattern, even in this simple case.

You are doing a die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); and print_r, as well as writing hello world, where do you actually view this!? As I mentioned fwrite this to a /tmp file to analyse.

I am working on the assumption of course that your service is running correctly.
What does the logcat say? Is their any discernible output indicating an issue?

The code itself on the php side looks somewhat hastily written, not being too critical here but some discipline here might save you many issues in the future. What does echo json_encode($variable); do at the end of the code for you?

Comment: How do i view the logd http traffic.... I view the Hello World on the web hosting site... the log cat does not show anything everything shows... getting my location.. the only problem is i not able to post it on the website...

Answer (score 0):

Just as a first guess, shouldn't line 3 be:

```
$json = $_POST['jsonpost'];//get the post you sent...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change line 3 to:

```
$json = $_REQUEST['jsonpost'];
```

You will support both POST and GET methods via HTTP. This can be useful if you are working in a development environment to make ensure requests are making it to your server without the specifics of an HTTP request.

$_REQUEST should be used with caution, as the variable will contain contents of $_COOKIES, $_GET and $_POST.

**You should always sanitize your data after accessing it in your script**

Comment: Still the same... Didnt get any of the values.. is there anything i am missing...?

Comment: What type of server is your PHP file served by, local, public, shared, etc?

Comment: I made a server using WAMP then i put my php file on site www.000webhost.com